# ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION following SQL Server Error 8114

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am writing in C++ against a SQL Server database. I have an object called `SQLTransaction` that when created at the start of a code block, sends 'begin transaction' to SQL Server.

I then send one or more SQL statements to the server. If all goes well, I set a flag in the `SQLTransaction` object to let it know the set of commands went well. When the `SQLTransaction` object then goes out of scope it either sends 'commit transaction' or 'rollback transaction to the server depending on the state of the flag.

It looks something like this:

```
    {
        TSQLTransaction SQLTran();

        try
        {
            Send( SomeSQLCommand );
        }
        catch(EMSError &e)
        {
            InformOperator();
            return;
        }

        SQLTran.commit();  
    }
```

I had a SQL statement in one of these blocks that sent a poor command and that command threw a SQL error 8114

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

I have since fixed that particular issue. What I don't understand is the fact that I was also receiving a second SQL error with the message

> The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

I can't find anything that tells me this transaction could or should not be rolled back after failure.

This exact same `SQLTransaction` object is used in many places in my application and always seemed to work correctly until now. This SQL error seems to be treated differently for some reason. Are there some errors that SQL Server automatically rolls back? I'd really like to understand what's happening here.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you put transaction logic inside of SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

There is a connection option, [SET XACT_ABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx), that determines the fate of current transaction(s) when SQL statement throws an error. Basically, when set to `OFF`, the transaction (usually) survives and execution continues; if it's `ON`, all opened transactions in the current connection are rolled back and batch is terminated.

The option could be set:

1. On the connection level;
2. Different database access drivers might have different defaults for connection options;
3. There is a default value on the SQL Server instance level.

Check whether any of these were changed recently. Also, if you capture the trace in the SQL Profiler, the "ExistingConnection" event lists current connection settings. You can always check the option state there, and rule it out if it's turned off. In that case, I would look closer at the trace, there might be additional commands sent to the server that aren't apparent from your client code.